# LINQ XML search failed with default attribue path

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I used the follwoing code to search the number of elements and search the search is succeeded only if there is no default path:

The code to search:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(@"c:\b.txt", LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
IEnumerable<XElement> address =
             from el in root.Elements("Address")
              select el;
int c = address.Count();
```

And the value for c is 2 with the following data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<presence xmlns:a="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf"
  xmlns:dm="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:data-model"
  xmlns:oma="urn:xml:prs:pidf:oma-pres"
  entity="sip:john@police.city.gov">
  <Address Type="Shipping">
    <Name>Ellen Adams</Name>
    <Street>123 Maple Street</Street>
    <City>Mill Valley</City>
    <State>CA</State>
    <Zip>10999</Zip>
    <Country>USA</Country>
  </Address>
  <Address Type="Billing">
    <Name>Tai Yee</Name>
    <Street>8 Oak Avenue</Street>
    <City>Old Town</City>
    <State>PA</State>
    <Zip>95819</Zip>
    <Country>USA</Country>
  </Address>
</presence>
```

But if I change the XML by exchanging the second line to be (xmlns instead of xmlns:a):

```
 <presence xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf"
```

I got value 0 which is incorrect.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf"` means, that you set default namespace for all elements in xml, that don't have any namespace specified.

As result,  you should also add namespace declaration to your LINQ to XML query, like so:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(@"c:\b.txt", LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);

XNamespace xmlns = "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf";

IEnumerable<XElement> address = root.Elements(xmlns + "Address");

Console.WriteLine(address.Count()); //prints 2
```

or you can use namespace agnostic approach, which will work regardless of what default namespace is specified:

```
var address = root.Elements()
                  .Where(node => node.Name.LocalName == "Address");
//address will contain the same nodes, as in previous example
```

Also note, that extension method syntax is much cleaner in such case.

Answer (score 4):

By setting xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf" you've set the default namespace for all elements. Therefore, the "Address" element no longer exists. It's called "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:Address" now.

What you need to do is declare an XNamespace and add that to the element name:

```
XNamespace defaultNamespace = "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf";
XElement root = XElement.Load(@"c:\b.txt", LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
IEnumerable<XElement> address =
             from el in root.Elements(defaultNamespace + "Address")
              select el;
int c = address.Count();
```